# How to make a delay for a function but don't execute again in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a shooting game in Javascript: the player will shoot one bullet and will delay for 2 seconds before shooting another one again. I don't know how to make a delay. Using `setTimeout`, it has a delay, but it will automatically call the function. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please add your current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, you want a system that prevents a function, say `shootBullet()` from being called until a delay is finished. The simplest way to do this is a global variable and a `setTimeout`:

```
var canShoot = true;

function shootBullet() {
    if (canShoot) {
        //Shoot bullet
    }
    canShoot = false;
    setTimeout(function() {
        canShoot = true;
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding, in this case, you need a function which was called "debounce" like this :

```
function debounce(func, wait) {
    let timeout;
    return () => { //create closure
      let context = this,
        args = arguments;

      let excuteFunction = () => {
        func.apply(context, args)
      }
      clearInterval(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(excuteFunction, wait);
    };
  }
```

when **func** is your shooting function and **wait** is the delay time.

You can read more about the debounce technique at [here](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function)

Or you can use the built-in debounce function in Lodash: [Lodash Docs](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce)